# Any performance hit to code inside a realm write for React Native?

Tags: react-native, realm

I've got a big switch case, and each case does a bit of work pulling together what it needs to make a particular database object, then realm.create's the object. The easiest way to ensure persistence is to chuck the whole switch/case inside a realm.write. Will this slow down the code running inside each case?

```
realm.write(() => {
  let x, y;
  switch (condition) {
    case 'x':
      x = //some work to generate the x object
      realm.create('X', x);
      break;
    case 'y':
      y = // some work to generate the y object
      realm.create('Y', y);
      break;
  }
});
```

The alternative is simply to use a variable to hold on to an arrow function with whatever case's create gets used, and call realm.write with that arrow function at the end. Happy to do this, but curious as to whether there is any benefit.

```
let x, y, writeFunc;
switch (condition) {
  case 'x':
    x = //some work to generate the x object
    writeFunc = () => realm.create('X', x);
    break;
  case 'y':
    y = // some work to generate the y object
    writeFunc = () => realm.create('Y', y);
    break;
}
realm.write(writeFunc);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your code examples will perform about the same. It's fine to execute other code inside your write block so I would choose whichever option is the cleanest/easiest.

When thinking about performance the only thing you need to really worry about is having too many transactions. Ideally you should minimize the number of transactions you have and to batch multiple operations (creation, mutation, deletion) inside a singe write transaction rather than having a transaction for each operation. When writing multiple objects simultaneously things can be sped up significantly and if you are performing many operations then batching them can have a real impact on performance.